# where is R file after compiled?

Tags: r

I have downloaded a  source tar file of `R-3.0.2.tar`(not binary R file),when i untar it ,there is a file named loess.R  in `/R-3.0.2/src/library/stats/R/`.
when i compiled it and install R,i can not find it in the installed directory.when i input

```
getAnywhere(loess)
```

what is the meaning of `<bytecode: 0x02d9a104>`  at the end of output info?
why i can see the source code  of loess and the loess.R is gone at the same time?
it is the fact that loess.R was compiled into a binary form .
1.In which binary file   loess.R  was compiled into?
2.if i have the binary file which contain loess.R,   i try to  decompile it into the source code of loess.R  to make a progress in my computer knowledge .maybe there   is a  decompile code in R now ,when input getAnywhere(loess) ,the code was called to work for its master right alway.
`bytecode: 0x02d9a104`  is the address in the compiled file contains loess.R?

```
list.files("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2", full.names=TRUE,recursive = TRUE )->x    
x[grep(pattern="stats",y)]    
 [1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/include/R_ext/stats_package.h"          "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/include/R_ext/stats_stubs.h"               
 [3] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/COPYRIGHTS.modreg"        "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/demo/glm.vr.R"               
 [5] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/demo/lm.glm.R"            "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/demo/nlm.R"                  
 [7] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/demo/smooth.R"            "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/DESCRIPTION"                 
 [9] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/help/aliases.rds"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/help/AnIndex"                
[11] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/help/paths.rds"           "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/help/stats.rdb"              
[13] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/help/stats.rdx"           "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/html/00Index.html"           
[15] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/html/R.css"               "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/INDEX"                       
[17] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/libs/i386/stats.dll"      "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/Meta/demo.rds"               
[19] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/Meta/hsearch.rds"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/Meta/links.rds"              
[21] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/Meta/nsInfo.rds"          "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/Meta/package.rds"            
[23] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/Meta/Rd.rds"              "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/NAMESPACE"                   
[25] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/R/stats"                  "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/R/stats.rdb"                 
[27] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/R/stats.rdx"              "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/SOURCES.ts"                  
[29] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/cmdscale.R"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/drop1-polr.R"          
[31] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/glm.R"              "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/glm.Rout.save"         
[33] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/ig_glm.R"           "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/ks-test.R"             
[35] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/ks-test.Rout.save"  "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/nafns.R"               
[37] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/nls.R"              "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/nls.Rout.save"         
[39] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/NLSstClosest.R"     "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/offsets.R"             
[41] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/ppr.R"              "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/ppr_test.csv"          
[43] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/simulate.R"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/simulate.Rout.save"    
[45] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/smooth.spline.R"    "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats/tests/ts-tests.R"            
[47] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/DESCRIPTION"             "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/help/aliases.rds"           
[49] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/help/AnIndex"            "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/help/paths.rds"             
[51] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/help/stats4.rdb"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/help/stats4.rdx"            
[53] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/html/00Index.html"       "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/html/R.css"                 
[55] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/INDEX"                   "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/Meta/hsearch.rds"           
[57] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/Meta/links.rds"          "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/Meta/nsInfo.rds"            
[59] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/Meta/package.rds"        "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/Meta/Rd.rds"                
[61] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/NAMESPACE"               "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/R/stats4"                   
[63] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/R/stats4.rdb"            "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/R/stats4.rdx"               
[65] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/stats4/tests/confint.R"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/share/dictionaries/en_stats.rds"           
[67] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/share/dictionaries/en_stats.txt"        "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/tests/Examples/stats-Ex.Rout.save"         
[69] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/tests/Examples/stats4-Ex.Rout.save"
```

Comment: The <bytecode: 0x02d9a104> line indicates that the function is **byte-compiled**, and you can still view the source from the R command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is in whatever directory your $R_HOME$ is set to. This is how I would determine that location on my machine (if I already didn't have that location memorized):

```
> R.home(component = "home")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

You prepend that value to the `/R-3.0.2/src/library/stats/R/` to get the location of loess.R on your machine. If you want to see how I figured this out (not actually knowing the details off the top of my head) then type:

```
?Startup
```

... and follow the links on that help page. My stats package is actually in a compiled package: `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/R/stats`. (I don't have the sources in my installation. Not a Unix savvy guy. Still using the compiled binary.)

Comment: No, the file lowess.R  and all other R source files do not exist in an installed version of R, they only exist in the R source.   Of course, the corresponding `loess`() function does exist, though in compiled and binary format, so R gets it much faster when the `stats` package is loaded and attached (typically at startup).

Comment: I thought he wanted to know where the compiled file was.

Comment: ok, I see; but @DWin you explicitly said ".. to get the location of loess.R". Instead, you there get *one* file  all.R in which you actually can find all of loess.R (search for the filename).  OTOH, the *binary* content is in `file.path(R.home(),"library","stats","R")` .. note, without the `src/` part, in the "database" file  stats.rdb (indexed by stats.rdx).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment @DWin, the `loess.R` file is no longer "there" after you've installed R; the content of all these R source files are (byte compiled and) stored much more efficiently, so R can very quickly load these objects, when asked to do so [for `loess`, typically at startup, when the `stats` package is loaded and attached].   This is entirely analogous to the  *.c and *.f  C and Fortran source files, you find in the R source.  These are all compiled (and linked) into object libraries, and the original source files are what they are: "in the source" ;-)